# Is SWAP on both hard disks needed?

Tags: ssd, swap

We have a 32GB RAM ubuntu along with 2 SDD of 240GB. When I view the sda and sdb, both have 32GB swap. Is that normal? I was expecting that only 1 swap of 32GB is needed? or do I need swap at all.

My ubuntu:

```
 # sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL

 NAME    FSTYPE              SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
 sda                       223.6G
 |-sda1  linux_raid_member   953M            XX-PH-0456-19:0
 | `-md0 ext4                953M /boot
 |-sda2  linux_raid_member    32G            XX-PH-0456-19:1
 | `-md1 swap                 32G [SWAP]
 `-sda3  linux_raid_member 190.7G            XX-PH-0456-19:2
   `-md2 ext4              190.7G /
 sdb                       223.6G
 |-sdb1  linux_raid_member   953M            XX-PH-0456-19:0
 | `-md0 ext4                953M /boot
 |-sdb2  linux_raid_member    32G            XX-PH-0456-19:1
 | `-md1 swap                 32G [SWAP]
 `-sdb3  linux_raid_member 190.7G            XX-PH-0456-19:2
   `-md2 ext4              190.7G /
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Children in bed, now here comes the extended edition.

## SWAP (do you need it?)

Well, basically you don't. **BUT**, if you got **none**, you **really** have to make **sure** that your 32GB of RAM is enough for the summed up RAM consumption of all running processes. If you don't the kernel will kill processes at its own gusto.

## Why are there two SWAP partitions?

This box is using a linux software raid with level 1. This means it mirrors the disks. Although you COULD theoretically destroy one of those SWAP partitions to use the disk space for something else (32GB should be enough) - I would strongly recommend against it.
If you would re-use sdb2 for example and if after some months or years of operation disk sda breaks, suddenly the amount of SWAP space will be 0.
So if now the RAM is fully used, linux will start to kill processes.

**To sum this up**: each disk in a raid 1 should provide everything that is necessary to operate the system on its own.

## What could you do to get more disk space?

Aside from getting a bigger server (the obvious way) you could rebuild the system and go without raid 1.
**BUT** be absolutely sure, you create regular backups and you can restore the system with those. Additionally you should be comfortable with the circumstance, that a failed disk means a downtime of the whole system until the disk is replaced and the system is restored from backup. (Which could, depending on hardware services and your own reaction time and skill, last up to several days. - Well you should ALWAYS make sure, recent backups are at hand, just in case the system fails one day - and it WILL.)

## Further Reads

additional information may be/is available at:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging#Linux
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive#SWAP
- http://makeuseof.com/tag/swap-partition

Comment: Your answer is very short. Please elaborate it a bit to improve its quality.

Comment: I will expand it as soon as I get to my PC. Just wanted to be sure he would not do stupid things because he got no answer at all.

Comment: hope this is sufficient :)  
if you got any questions - ask away.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I need some time to "digest" the knowledge. Will accept it as soon as I understand it

Comment: additional information may be/is available at:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging#Linux , 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive#SWAP ,
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/swap-partition/